# How to destructure in a correct way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm wondering how to return state with fetched array in a correct way using spread operator.

So here is my reducer:

```
function themes(state = [], actions){
  switch(actions.type){
    case FETCH_THEMES_SUCCESSFULLY:
      const { themes } = actions.theme;
      return {
        ...state,
        ...themes
      }
    default :
      return state;
  }
};
```

*actions* contains `array` called `themes`. But when `themes` is fetched my `props` looks like :

`{ themes: { themes: [...]} }`  instead of `{ themes: [] }`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actions.theme` is already your `[…]`; you don't need to destructure it any further. Replace `const { themes } = actions.theme` with `const themes = actions.theme` should get you the shape you're looking for.

Alternately, `const { themes } = actions;` would also work. But not both destructuring *and* accessing `actions.theme`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Destructure `themes` from `actions` and return it with the `state`

```
function themes(state = [], actions){
  switch(actions.type){
    case FETCH_THEMES_SUCCESSFULLY:
      const { themes } = actions;
      return {
        ...state,
        themes
      }
    default :
      return state;
  }
};
```